# How to give credit to someone else when writing an answer based on a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, best-practice

Let's say I posted a question. I did or didn't get some answers. But I also received some comments. Among them, one comment either answered my question or gave me hint to answer my own question. What's the proper way to give credit to the comment or the person that wrote that comment?

Comment: If someone answered your question, you can also ask them to post that comment as an answer so you can accept it and/or upvote it.

Answer (score 14):

Copy the link of the comment and add it to the question replacing the title of the comment by the user’s name. Something like this:

This comment from rinzwind helped me get there: [How to give credit to someone else when writing an answer based on a comment?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18998/how-to-give-credit-to-someoe-else-when-writing-an-answer-based-on-a-comment/18999#comment40782_18999)

I did that by clicking on the time next to my name in the comment and copying the link into the answer.

Comment: This is a comment!

Answer (score 8):

You can give credit to a comment (like "[Dan's comment](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18998/39012#comment40784_18998) helped me"), but if someone has posted an answer in the comments, I will usually encourage them to post an answer, but after some time, I will post it as an answer myself and put a note like:

> This answer came from [a comment by Dan](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18998/39012#comment40784_18998).

Because we really need to break the habit of posting answers in comments. If someone has posted an answer in the comments for your question, you have an obligation to post it as an answer if they don't. Answers don't belong in comments.